# MSE during Neural Network training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

Is it possible that the MSE increases during training?

I'm currently calculating the MSE of the validation set per epoch and at a certrain point, the MSE starts to increase instead of decreasing. Does someone has an explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering your question: Yes, it is possible.

If you are using regularization or estochastic training it is normal some ups and downs on the MSE while training.

**Some possible reasons to the problem**

1. You are using a learning rate too high, which let to the problem of overshooting the local minima of the cost function.
2. The neural network is overfitting. Traning too much and loosing its capabilities to generalize.

**What you can try:**

1. When this starts to happen, reduce your learning rate.
2. Apply some kind of regularization on your network, like dropout, to avoid overfitting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I thought about the learning rate, too. Overfitting is a good point. Didn't had this on my mind. Do you know any good approach to adjust the learning rate?

Comment: You can do it manually, detect when the MSE is increasing and reduce the learning rate one decimal. If you are using 0.01 change it to 0.001, for example. If you are using stochastic gradient descent as your optimization function you can search for optimization algorithms, like Adam  https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980. Tensorflow has Adam optimizer implemented. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I will have a look at Adam and implement it if possible. I'm often too lazy to do things manually:) From your experience: Is weight decay worth to implement as regularization?

Comment: No problem! Hope you solve your problem. Sorry, I'm just starting in machine learning/deep learning and never used weight decay =/. I used dropout and had good results. Check it out, its a very simple implementation: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/JMLRdropout.pdf